Visual Studio 2022 not showing DevOps projects in Team Explorer
I am using Visual Studio Professional 2022 and have a free Azure DevOps account linked to my personal Microsoft account. However, when I connect this account in Team Explorer it doesn't show me any of my DevOps projects which I can see when I am logged into the https://dev.azure.com portal. It only shows me a single project titled 'myname0488' which I have never created.
If I do the same in Visual Studio 2019 I can see my projects hosted in Azure DevOps and can connect and successfully clone repositories.
Can anyone advise how I get this working in VS 2022 and maybe explain why it works in VS 2019 but not in 2022.
Thanks in advance.

I am able to see my Project from Devops in VisualStudio

Based on your description, if the Azure DevOps organization that you expected to connect in VS was not backed with any Microsoft Entra ID (Fomerly AAD), you should be able to sign-in VS Team Explore and list the organization with your Microsoft Account.

You also mentioned it listed another organization that you never created, which could be an organization baked with another Azure tenant and where your personal account was invited as a guest user. You may double check if you can visit your MSA organization in the web browser and change the Account options to reauthenticate accounts using System web browser.

In case your origination is not an MSA organization but an AAD organization, you may verify whether the tenant filter is set correctly. And you can also check the sign-in failure logs in the AAD that this Azure DevOps organization is connected to. The sign-in activities may be affected and blocked by Azure Conditional Access Polies as well.
Beside, you may consider running the git clone <ADORepoURL> command as a workaround.

Hi Alvin, thanks very much for your help. Clicking on 'Account options' and reauthenticating my accounts using 'System web browser' did the trick. Great work thanks..
